# Can't resolve method getInputStream()

Tags: java, android

I am creating app in Android studio I implemeted a method but getting error: can't resolve method "getInputStream"

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new 
InputStreamReader(clienSocket.getInputStream()));
```

`.getInputStream()` method not resolving

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have declared clienSocket correctly or maybe you have done a mistake because in your question the name is "clienSocket" and maybe you wanted to write "clientSocket".

Look this example of socket:

```
String hostName = args[0];
int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

try (
    Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    PrintWriter out =
        new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in))
)
```